# Cloning a private Github repo as a collaborator when I have multiple accounts

Tags: git, github, git-clone, repository, multiple-accounts

I have 2 GitHub accounts:

**account1**

**account2**

In account2 I'm added as collaborator of a certain repo:

**account_notmine/repo_xyz**

I've created and added a new ssh key for the second account, and also added it on github.

```
Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host github-new
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_new
```

Now, if I try to work on one of my personal repositories of account2, it works fine. But when I try to clone the repo of which I'm a collaborator, it doesn't work.

Basically, all that I'm doing is trying to execute this command:

```
git clone --bare git@github-new:account_notmine/repo_xyz.git
```

And the error it gives me is:

```
Cloning into bare repository 'repo_xyz.git'...
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: just by calling my github second account via SSH (ssh -T git@github-new), I discovered that it answered me:

```
Hi **account1**! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not
# provide shell access.
```

Then I edited my ssh config file adding the **IdentitiesOnly yes** statement:

```
Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  IdentitiesOnly yes

Host github-smartstay
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_new
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Well, it worked.